# How to get x position and width from cross-tab in formula?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have cross-tab and i want put second cross-tab to right side, but i must know x position and width from first cross-tab.
Or any other idea how to realize two cross-tab in horizontal line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide this problem. Set on x position countcolumn * columnwith.